# Django queryset filter by array

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'my_user'
    ...
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interest, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

I have to write two queries:

1) Get MyUsers which have interest_id = 1 or 5 or 4.

2) Get MyUsers which have interest_id = 1 and 5 and 4.

My data base is PostgreSQL.

I wrote SQL query for first case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT myuser_id FROM my_user_interests WHERE interest_id = ANY(array[1,5,4]);
```

but I can't wtire it for the second case.

And anyway I need to do it with Django ORM, because further I need to do edit this queryset by new parameters and I can't do it if I use .raw()..

Help me please.

Comment: Have you tried: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#in ?

Comment: How is that SQL different from `... WHERE interest_id IN [1, 5, 4]`)?

Comment: Brandon, Yes, but it doesn't work correct. users = users.filter(interests__in=[1, 5, 4])

Daniel, ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ...CT * FROM my_user_interests WHERE interest_id IN [1, 5, 4]

Comment: Brandon, I was wrong, "__in" is correct way to do the first case, but the solution of the second case still open..

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem/

1)

```
users = users.filter(interests__in=[1, 5, 4])
```

2)

```
list_ = [1, 5, 4]
for i in len(list_):
    users = users.filter(interests=i)
```